# Renaming duplicates in excel (in a group)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

I have an excel chart with thousands of Samples in one column. The sample appears in a row three times matching up to a different column called Target which is normal. I am looking to seeing if the sample duplicates 4,5 or 6 times and add a "-r2" to the end of the Sample name, and if the Sample duplicates 7,8, or 9 times and add a "-r3" to the end of the Sample name. I am trying to find a formula that ignores the first three times a Sample is counted and only count duplicates from ranges 4-6 as "-r2" and 7-9 as "-r3".

Below is an example of what I would want my new column (called "New Sample") to look like. It's worth noting that not every sample is duplicated more than 3 times, sometimes 6 or 9.

| Sample | New Sample | Target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | top |
| 1 | 1 | middle |
| 1 | 1 | bottom |
| 1 | 1-r2 | top |
| 1 | 1-r2 | middle |
| 1 | 1-r2 | bottom |
| 1 | 1-r3 | top |
| 1 | 1-r3 | middle |
| 1 | 1-r3 | bottom |
| 2 | 2 | top |
| 2 | 2 | middle |
| 2 | 2 | bottom |
| 3 | 3 | top |
| 3 | 3 | middle |
| 3 | 3 | bottom |
| 3 | 3-r2 | top |
| 3 | 3-r2 | middle |
| 3 | 3-r2 | bottom |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=A2&IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$C$2:C2,C2)>1,"-r"&COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$C$2:C2,C2),"")
```

[image]

If the third column does not exist or we cannot refer to it:

```
=A2&IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2)>3,"-r"&INT((COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2)-1)/3)+1,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for responding. I understand the function, but I keep getting 'there's a problem with this formula message' when typing into the first Sample. I don't know if there's a missing parenthesis on the first COUNTIFS or if something else. But I assume it works on your end.

Comment: do you use `;` instead of `,` for the delimiter?

Comment: No I used a comma

Comment: but does your local setting require the use of `;` instead.  for example does: `=IF(1=1;1;0)` work?